# Destroying an element destroys a bind on that element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I'm trying to optimize my jQuery code by unbinding elements anytime is necessary, or that I need to  re-bind them, but I have a question, does "destroying" an element also destroys the event attached to that element?

```
$(element).bind("click", function(){...});
$(element).parent().html("");
```

Also I'm not sure if this is done with the .html(""), do I have to use a .remove() to do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you use jQuery methods to add/remove elements and bind events, all should be fine. When you bind an event to an element (or use something like `.data()`), jQuery stores this information in a place called `$.cache`. When you use jQuery methods to manipulate the DOM, jQuery takes care of cleaning up these things - because there really is no actual connection between the elements and `$.cache`. So if you added a div to the page, bound a `click` event to it with jQuery, then removed it with `node.parentNode.removeChild(node);`, `$.cache` is not cleaned up. If you would like evidence, look in the jQuery source for the methods like `html`, `remove`, `replaceWith` and similar ones, and you'll find calls like this:

```
jQuery.cleanData( elem.getElementsByTagName("*") );
jQuery.cleanData( [ elem ] );
```

This effectively cleans up the `$.cache` so that everything is taken care of. The point is that if you use the library for (everything) you do, you shouldn't have to worry about these things.

Using `html` is tricky though - be careful what you pass to it. If you want to pass it a new DOM structure, like

```
var div = $("<div>")
              .attr("id", "div1")
              .click(function () {
                  alert("clicked");
              });
```

Using something like `$("#container").html(div);` will not actually bind that click event handler. Using something like `.append` will though. Just wanted to point that out. (this is unrelated to destroying/removing elements)

Comment: Awesome answer and interesting btw, yeah I'm aware that binded events only work on elements that exists only when the bind is done; that's why I unbind-bind elements when reloading, the problem this time is when I have so many elements is better to empty or destroy the parent instead of unbinding 200 elements. I will try your solution and post if I have any problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the element, the DOM will no longer be listening for clicks inside that element.

.remove should do the trick.

```
$(element).parent().remove();
```

Will remove the element from the DOM.

Comment: By the way, how big is your app/site?

Comment: `$(element).parent().remove();` removes the parent - you don't want to do that. `$(element).remove()` will work just fine.

Comment: The `.on`/`.bind` remark is totally off-topic... and IMO you did not answer the question. Yes, if you remove an element with `.html` then it cannot trigger events anymore, but do the event listeners still exist?

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was just using his example, and not assuming that he wanted to remove the element, but its parent. :)

Comment: .on/.bind comment is absolutely on topic. .bind will be deprecated soon, thus making .bind obsolete @FelixKling.

Comment: But that's not the question here. It's ok to mention this in a comment, but half of your answer is about it, in between things that seem to address the question more, which makes it look like an important part of the answer... it is not though.

Comment: I would also suggest using .on instead of .bind. This is a quote from the jQuery website:

As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the
 .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to
 elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in
 the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call
 to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().

Comment: The problem is a part of the site that can grow really big, because I need to auto-load 20 results (and bind each result) every time, at some point I need to "refresh" these results and If I have 200 listeners at the same time I'm afraid it can get really slow, I'm using "on" on the parent container for some events, but some other events can't be binded that way.